# Progress bar on webpage

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

I want to display an animated gif on my webpage for some time consuming tasks.
There is an AJAX updateprogress control for that to this, but as i've seen on 
Matt Berseth's blog [link text](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/10/yui_style_ajax_progress_indica.html)  he uses UpdatePanelAnimationExtender from AJAX toolkit.

Can you explain why he needs the UpdatePanelAnimationExtender?
What is better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

He explains it himself:

> For this sample, I also incorporated a
>   technique I described here that allows
>   you to render the progress panel
>   directly over a specific control.  To
>   accomplish this, I am calculating the
>   center of the control and manually
>   placing the progress panel over the
>   center of the rendered GridView.  I
>   make this calculation using the
>   OnUpdating and OnUpdated animations of
>   the UpdatePanelAnimationExtende